# Pen acting like touch in word 2010

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

With navigating Word 2010 documents on Windows 10, using the pen is interpreted as though it was touch. While the pen is correctly detected as a pen elsewhere in windows (with the special cursor), in Word the cursor is an I-beam and it will just move the window unless I tap to move the caret to a certain location, then if I drag from that location it will select text. In windows 7 it behaved more like a mouse, meaning it will not drag the window, just select text. Any ideas what would cause this? I'm on a corporate machine and they have a habit of accidentally messing with settings and not realizing it. This is a Yoga X1.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010 you'll need to explicitly start the "Ink tools" to have it behave as a pen.

I haven't got a copy of 2010 handy but there should be a button called "Start Inking" on the Review tab.

Comment: I should have noted - I'm not interesting in inking, I want it to behave like a mouse. But yes, there is a ink tools tab available.